# What IntelliJ plugin(hint to jump to a specific line) is used in this video?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, editor

The video can be viewed at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCVwdvufTds

I was wondering what plugin is used in the video to enable the `hint` for each line so that he can jump to any line with one key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here it is](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=6311), from the same guy who uploaded the video.

Comment: AceJump is just a version of the same plugin with less features. Notice the same author and the very similar description.

Comment: Still -- the author himself (John Lindquist) mentioned AceJump in comments to another video and even has video about this plugin when he mention that this is the plugin he used when making his tutorial videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yK8eM50DsAY P.S. -1 is not from me -- it was before I commented